# opencv2/opencv.hpp no such file or directory

Tags: ros-melodic, opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am on jetson using ROS melodic version. I am receiving no such file or directory for opencv2/opencv.hpp. I know I am not linking it properly but not sure how to fix it.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(camera)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  message_generation
  message_runtime
)


generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
   CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge image_transport roscpp rospy sensor_msgs std_msgs message_generation
  message_runtime
)

include_directories( 
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} 

)

link_directories(
        /opt/ros/melodic/lib
)

set(CATKIN_LIBS cv_bridge.so image_transport.so message_filters.so class_loader.so dl.so roslib.so rospack.so python2.7.so             boost_program_options.so tinyxml2.so roscpp.so boost_filesystem.so rosconsole.so rosconsole_log4cxx.so rosconsole_backend_interface.so log4cxx.so boost_regex.so xmlrpcpp.so roscpp_serialization.so rostime.so cpp_common.so boost_system.so boost_thread.so boost_chrono.so boost_date_time.so boost_atomic.so pthread.so console_bridge.so)


find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(PKG_OPENCV REQUIRED opencv)

add_executable(capture src/camera_node.cpp )
add_dependencies(capture ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(capture ${CATKIN_LIBS} ${PKG_OPENCV_LDFLAGS} ${V4l2_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(detect src/person_detection_node.cpp )
add_dependencies(detect ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(detect ${CATKIN_LIBS} ${PKG_OPENCV_LDFLAGS} ${V4l2_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(sample_detection_sub src/sample_detection_sub.cpp )
add_dependencies(sample_detection_sub ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(sample_detection_sub ${CATKIN_LIBS}  ${PKG_OPENCV_LDFLAGS} ${V4l2_LIBRARIES})
```

Above is my Cmakelist.txt
Below is my opencv Installation procedure

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386779/opencv2/opencv.hpp-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2021-09-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-17**:
Please show us the command you used to install the opencv development package.

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2021-09-20**:
Hi Mike,
I had attached the image for OpenCV installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed problem by changing path in cv_bridgeConfig.cmake file on line 94 and line 96 form /usr/include/opencv or /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2 to /usr/include/opencv4 and then it worked.
Not proper path was mentioned

---

Originally posted by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) with karma: 126 on 2021-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-20**:
Each release of ros is very specific about the version of opencv the binary packages use. For melodic, it wants v3.2.0. By installing a different version of opencv, you may discover down the road that you have created a conflict that will need to be resolved.

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2021-09-20**:
got it, I will see if I can go lower version for OpenCV
thanks

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-20**:
For ubuntu 18, opencv is in the ubuntu package repository, so you don't have to build it from source. Have you tried installing ubuntu package `libopencv-dev`?

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2021-09-21**:
Actually, I am integrating with another SDK that needs OpenCV version 4.4.0 due to which I cannot go back or change my installation procedure.